# Silverlight Compilation error in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight

I have changed the code in my cs file and compiled compiled the code with no error but still I am getting to see old output and and not the new output which is desired after changing the code in my silverlight application.Any idea why this happening.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to clear your browser cache. Browser caches the xap packages.

Answer (score 2):

Try to build, rebuild and clean the solution several times. This happens.

Comment: i have done that several times but output its not changing.Actually it was working yesterday if introduce error and build it and remove the error and again build it.but from today this method is also not working.Any other option then please do suggest.